# VBA fill summary table from a changing list

Tags: vba, excel

My idea is I have a list of names within a workbook sheet.

This list may get updated from time to time when new teammates are added. I then have have summary table on a separate sheet.

What I need is for this list to populate column A of the summary table whenever the list gets updated, and then also apply formulas across the other columns if a name is within a row of column A of the summary table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Right now, I have it manually adding names to each row of column A and then searching for the name in other sheets, etc. I'm ultimately trying to make it so that instead of manually adding the names through code, someone who isn't familiar with VBA can instead add the names to a different sheet under a list and then have that pull to generate the list and then have the code search for those names and apply the correct formulas.

Any help would be great! here is my code for right now, but I wish I could include what I mentioned in the beginning (with a sheet that has a list of names that pulls from there and can get updated). This code works, but requires someone to update the code if a new teammate is added...

```
Sub Summary()
    'Summary table Team
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.name = "Summary"

'Making the Table
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(13, "G")).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

Cells(1, "A").Value = "Header 1"
Cells(1, "B").Value = "Header 2"
Cells(1, "C").Value = "header 3"
Cells(1, "D").Value = "header 4"
Cells(1, "E").Value = "header 5"
Cells(1, "F").Value = "header 6"
Cells(1, "G").Value = "header 7"

Cells(2, "A").Value = "John"
Cells(3, "A").Value = "Bob"
Cells(4, "A").Value = "Laura"
Cells(5, "A").Value = "Linda"
Cells(6, "A").Value = "Lucy"
Cells(7, "A").Value = "Alice"
Cells(8, "A").Value = "Margret"
Cells(9, "A").Value = "Matt"
Cells(10, "A").Value = "Steve"
Cells(11, "A").Value = "Tim"
Cells(12, "A").Value = "Luke"
Cells(13, "A").Value = "Tara"

Range("A1:I1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Adding the Formulas for the Table

Worksheets("Summary").Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B13").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!G:G,Summary!A2)"
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C13").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Sheet2'!G:G,Summary!A2)"
ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D13").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Sheet3'!G:G,Summary!A2)"
ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E13").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Sheet4'!G:G,Summary!A2)"
ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F13").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Sheet5'!G:G,Summary!A2)"
ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G13").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('Sheet6'!G:G,Summary!A2)"

'Adding conditional formatting
    Range("B2:G13").Select
Selection.formatconditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=0"
Selection.formatconditions(Selection.formatconditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.formatconditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.formatconditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.formatconditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.formatconditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=0"
Selection.formatconditions(Selection.formatconditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.formatconditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.formatconditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.formatconditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Also fairly new to vba so I know this code is ugly, but it works lol! Just looking for help on how to fix it so that it is less manual updating of names and more dynamic.

Comment: Trying to see if I understand right....... you want someone to be able to add a sheet( sheet b) to the workbook and have the code go through each line. Everytime the name is found on a seperate sheet(sheet a) it will search for the name in (sheet a) and apply the formula to the row in (sheet a) where the name is found??

Answer (score 0):

I recognize your effort in solving this problem using VBA, but I strongly believe you are over-complicating things. Excel's core features are better suited to solving your problem here in a faster, more efficient way than using custom VBA code.

To solve your problem, create a dynamic named range to hold your list of names. This way whenever you need to add a name in the future it will be automatically added throughout the workbook. In the ribbon, click on Formulas, Name Manager, Add (I called mine 'names', and assuming your list of names are in column A on Sheet1:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)
```

To use the name on the on other worksheet, simply use `=names`.

In regards to the formulas on the other sheet, I would use placeholders. For example, you are using `=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!G:G,Summary!A2)` in column B of your Summary worksheet. Fill column B with your formula but add an `IF` statement in front. So it will become `=IF($A2=0,"",COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!G:G,Summary!A2))`. This will make the rows with no names blank.

Add your formatting as you normally would without VBA.

You can now test by adding a name and everything will update. Let me know if you need any additional help.